# CollectionNotInitializedException

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, list-view

I slightly modified this example of how to [use CSOM to display a list's current views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee538275%28v%3Doffice.15%29).

I'm getting the following error: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException: 'The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.'"

Here is my code:

```
using (ClientContext cc = new ClientContext("https://demo.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName"))
        {
            var passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

            cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("test@demo.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

            Web oWeb = cc.Web;
            List oList = oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Test List");
            ViewCollection oViewCollection = oList.Views;

            cc.Load(oWeb);
            cc.Load(oList);
            cc.Load(oViewCollection);

            cc.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(oWeb.Title);
            Console.WriteLine(oList.Title);

            foreach (View oneView in oViewCollection) //error occurs
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oneView.Title);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

How can I resolve the error, so that I can loop through all of the view names and write them to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and SharePoint.Client.Runtime via NuGet, but I had not installed Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM. Once I uninstalled the above packages and installed Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM, the code ran correctly.

[This article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/using-correct-csom-version-for-sharepoint-customizations/) gives more details regarding which NuGet package to use for SP 2013, 2016 and Online.

Answer (score 0):

try below code, while you load the view, you need to `Include` the fields you want to retrieve.

```
using (ClientContext cc = new ClientContext("https://demo.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName"))
        {
            var passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

            cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("test@demo.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

            Web oWeb = cc.Web;
            List list = oWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Test List");
            ViewCollection viewColl = list.Views;
            cc.Load(viewColl,
                views => views.Include(
                    view => view.Title,
                    view => view.Id)); 
            cc.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (View view in viewColl)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(view.Title + "--------" + view.Id);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: With that code, I get the same error as with my original code.

Comment: Is your list name correct??

Comment: Yes, the list name is correct. I am able to output the list name.